# Accessing the modified rule file from Kie Workbench

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie-wb

I need to use the rules defined using the guided rules editor from Kie Workbench in my GWT application.  I believe once the user adds/modifies and saves the the rule, it will be saved to the git repository.

I have tried the approach where I can modify the rules and then build and deploy, it will be deployed to local maven repository as an artifact which can be accessed via HTTP and execute the rules as mentioned [Loading Drools/KIE Workbench artifacts directly from the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186570/loading-drools-kie-workbench-artifacts-directly-from-the-repository/23132265#23132265). But this approach is not useful for me (since we have to build and deploy whenever user edits the rule file).

Can you please suggest how to get the modified rule file whenever user edits and saves it from Kie Workbench in a Java/GWT application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but let my answer as i understood.
Whenever your rules files is changed you can use workbench REST api to build your workbench project remotely. Here is the documentation on API 
http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html/wb.WorkbenchIntegration.html#d0e17059