# Set event processing to STREAM with rules from a Maven project (KieScanner)

Tags: spring-boot, drools

I have a Maven project with rules in `.drl` files and another project, which is a `SpringBoot` web server. The rules can be sent by a POST request to the server, after which they are added to the Maven project and can be activated like they were there from the start.

The rules are "noticed" because I update the Maven rules project (by calling its `mvn clean install`) each time a new rule is submitted.

I tried a lot of configurations, the most "logical" shots being these two below:

First try:

```
@Bean
public KieSession kieSession() {
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(ks.newReleaseId("ftn.bsep9","drools-spring-kjar", "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"));

    KieBaseConfiguration config = ks.newKieBaseConfiguration();
    config.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);

    KieBase kieBase = kContainer.newKieBase("myKBase", config);
    KieSession kSession = kieBase.newKieSession();

    KieScanner kScanner = ks.newKieScanner(kContainer);
    kScanner.start(10000); // check for rule changes every 10 seconds

    return kSession;
}
```

...

N-th try:

```
@Bean
public KieSession kieSession() {
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();
    KieModuleModel kModule = ks.newKieModuleModel();

    KieBaseModel baseModel = kModule.newKieBaseModel("defaultKieBase")
            .setDefault(true)
            .setEventProcessingMode(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);
    baseModel.newKieSessionModel("defaultKSession")
            .setDefault(true)
            .setClockType(ClockTypeOption.get("pseudo"));

    kfs.writeKModuleXML(kModule.toXML());
    KieBuilder kieBuilder = ks.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();
    System.out.println("ERRORS: " + kieBuilder.getResults().getMessages(Message.Level.ERROR).size());

    KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(ks.newReleaseId(
            "ftn.bsep9","drools-spring-kjar", "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"));
    KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession();

    KieScanner kScanner = ks.newKieScanner(kContainer);
    kScanner.start(10000); // check for rule changes every 10 seconds

    return kSession;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, especially with an explanation of why Your code works and my doesn't. :)

---

**Note:** the code below works, but I can't use the `over window:time(5m)` drools' expression, since it requires the **STREAM** `EventProcessing`.

```
@Bean
    public KieSession kieSession() {
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(ks.newReleaseId("ftn.bsep9","drools-spring-kjar", "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"));
        KieScanner kScanner = ks.newKieScanner(kContainer);
        kScanner.start(10000);
        return kContainer.newKieSession();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the the problem by setting the dependencies correctly. I am using `6.2.0.Final` version of the `kie-ci` and `kie-spring` artifacts. I tried versions: `7.7.0`, `7.2.0`, `6.5.0` and `6.4.0`, but none of them worked.

`KieSession` Bean is being created as follows:

```
@Bean
public KieSession kieSession() {
    final KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    final ReleaseId releaseId = kieServices.newReleaseId(groupId, artifactId, version);
    final KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(releaseId);
    final KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();

    final KieScanner kieScanner = kieServices.newKieScanner(kieContainer);
    kieScanner.start(10000);

    log.warn(":) created a KIE Container - returning...");
    return kieSession;
}
```

Part of the [pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/AleksandarSavic95/5e6514356ac181ed5544e841f440b9f3) file containing KIE artifacts' version is below:

```
...
<properties>
    <kie.version>6.2.0.Final</kie.version>
</properties>
...
<dependencies>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
    <version>${kie.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${kie.version}</version>
</dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

What helped in the process was running `mvn dependency:tree` and checking which versions of which artifacts/projects are being used.

Here is the link to [the complete pom.xml file](https://gist.github.com/AleksandarSavic95/5e6514356ac181ed5544e841f440b9f3) which worked for me.
Dependency tree generated from `mvn dependency:tree` can be found [||here||](https://gist.github.com/AleksandarSavic95/80c50a4ed65a3ca2ce1341317d311302).