# KIE Workbench: How to triggers rules in workbench from java application?

Tags: java, kie-workbench, drools-kie-server, kie-server, drools-kie-workbench

I have installed KIE Workbench and KIE server on Docker.I have the artifact in drools workbench. Now I am trying to run the artifact from eclipse. 
I tried doing this :

```
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(
            ks.newReleaseId("com.myteam",   "test1", "1.0.0"));

    KieScanner kScanner = ks.newKieScanner( kContainer );
    kScanner.start( 10000L );
    KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("default");
```

However I am getting a runtime exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: com.myteam:test1:1.0.0
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:186)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:172)
at com.sample.Invoke.main(Invoke.java:12)
```

I found in this link :
[Loading Drools/KIE Workbench artifacts directly from the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186570/loading-drools-kie-workbench-artifacts-directly-from-the-repository?noredirect=1&lq=1) . I want to try this approach.

But I am not sure what the url should be because the url in my pom file is a file path. I have attached the screen shot of pom file. [Screen shot of the pom file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKtL4.png)

I checked the log of KIE Server. I have attached the screen shot of the the log.[KIE Server LOG Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QIBg.png). When I navigate to that url. I get an error message saying "took too long to respond".

Thanks