# Using compareTo() for date comparison in drools

Tags: java, drools, compareto

I am trying to compare two dates in DRL file using compareTo().However, I am facing an issue when I use new Date() as the argument to the compareTo() method.

eg:

```
loanDatePaid.compareTo(date2)==0
```

is working but

```
loanDatePaid.compareTo(new Date())==0
```

is giving

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: org.default:artifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:186)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:172)
```

Can anyone suggest why it is so?

PS: The exception posted above is standard one which is coming for all errors in drl execution at runtime. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-usage/LHRKHkO35RI

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: could you use java 8 Date and Time API or are you forced to stick with the old one ?

Comment: You asked the same question 3 hours ago in a different thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458466/cannot-find-kiemodule-org-defaultartifact1-0-0-snapshot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find KieModule: org.default:artifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458466/cannot-find-kiemodule-org-defaultartifact1-0-0-snapshot)

Comment: @EstebanAliverti As in the comment of IntellijAMiya in the post - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-usage/LHRKHkO35RI. 

All errors in the drl give this standard error and the two questions are different in the sense this question specifically asks why compareTo() is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the dependency for the module. Have a look at a similar issue in this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995133/why-does-loading-drools-6-kie-jar-into-code-fail)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the drl execution facing errors at runtime gives the standard error posted above. For more info: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-usage/LHRKHkO35RI

Also, this is a misnomer as this leads in a wrong direction.

The issue was that I was not importing java.util.Date class for initialization of new Date().